# echo json_encoded($array) passes previous echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I don't know jQuery so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

When i passes value from php to javascript even previous message printed with echo are passed, how could I avoid this?

php

```
  $Connection = new Connection("...");
  $array = $Connection->arrCol("SELECT IT FROM global", "IT");
  echo json_encode($array);
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("services/test.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
 });
```

result

> **CONNECTED at (localhost) (user: root) (db: ...)  stausUptime:
>   440790 Threads: 1 Questions: 1244 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 53 Flush
>   tables: 1 Open tables: 1 Queries per second avg: 0.2** (message "echoed" by method of Connection in php)
>
> ["..."] (requested data)

Comment: im not understanding what you want

Comment: i want php sends ONLY array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Connection` class does an echo and you don't want that mixed into your JSON output, you will have to control the output buffer.

For example:

```
// Start catching the output
ob_start();

// Run code that echoes unwanted stuff under the hood
$Connection = new Connection("...");
$array = $Connection->arrCol("SELECT IT FROM global", "IT");

// Clear the output buffer and stop buffering (i.e. discard that echo)
ob_end_clean();

// Output JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) in php.

Call the `ob_start();` function at the beginning of your php code, and before your last echo statement call `ob_end_clean();` to clean the output buffer from the previous echo/print statements.